# Count Palindrome Words in a string

Tags: c++, string

You are given a string s of words. Your task is to find the number of palindrome  words in the given string S. A word is called palindrome if it read the same from backward as well as forward. Words are separated by one or more whitespaces

**problem- When I am giving string only as "Deed"  it is giving 1 which is correct but when I am giving string as "I Deed" it is showing 1 but it should show 2.**
**I have attached the code below.**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
char toLowerCase(char ch)
{
    if(ch>='A' && ch<='Z')
    {
        ch=ch-'A'+'a';
    }
    return ch;
}
int countNumberOfPalindromeWords(string s)
{
    //Your code goes here
    int st=0,e=0;
    int lengt=s.length();
    int cnt=0;
    while(st<lengt && e<lengt)
    {
        if(s[e]!=' ')
        {
            string temp="";
        while(e<lengt && s[e]!=' ')
        {
         temp+=toLowerCase(s[e]);
         e++;
        }

        int i=st;
        int j=e-1;
        bool isPalindrome=true;
        while(i<=j)
        {
            if(temp[i]!=temp[j])
            {
                isPalindrome=false;
                break;
            }
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        if(isPalindrome)
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        st=e;
        
        }
        else{
            e++;
            st++;

        }

    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with C++, but here is some python code that accomplishes this task.

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    return word.lower() == word.lower()[::-1]

def countNumberOfPalindromeWords(s):
    words = s.split()
    palindrome_count = 0

    for word in words:
        if is_palindrome(word):
            palindrome_count += 1

    return palindrome_count

# Example usage:
input_string = "level Civic radar python Deed kayak"
result = countNumberOfPalindromeWords(input_string)
print("Number of palindrome words:", result)
```

Using this information you should be able to use a python to C++ converter if needed.